# Symfony 1.4 Import resource yml

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, symfony-1.4

In Symfony 1.4 I would like share config between `*.yml` files. Can I do so like in Symfony >=2.0?

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do an include or require. Symfony autoloads config files into its sfConfig object.

All you need to do is place it

in `root/lib` if you want it available through the project or

in `root/apps/frontend/lib` if you want only in that application or

lastly in `root/apps/frontend/modules/modulename/config` for a specific module even.

Comment: I have few configs for different environments. Generally, all environments will share a large base of common configuration.  I would like share common configuration, like described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html#different-environments-different-configuration-files

Answer (score 0):

you can include configuration using php within YAML file

```
#myconfig.yml
my_config:
    foo: bar
```

and then import using php and the key `myconfig`

```
#parameters.yml
<?php include 'myconfig.yml'; ?>
...
```

I don't know if it will work or not, but I'm sure about using php within YAML file.